# Delete individual texts with iOS 8?

Tags: ios

I have the new iOS 8, and am having problems deleting texts. I have restarted my iPhone several times and it fixes it for about 2 minutes-then the camera pops back up and no trash can at the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

Tap/hold a message, wait for the pop-up.
Tap More.
That Marks a single message.
Continue to tap more messages to Mark them, or hit the Trash can or Share icon, as desired.